# Failed to desirialize heterogeneous json data

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

So I am using Json.net to deserialize json data returned by REST APIs to a server, the data structure it returns is:

```
{ "keyXXX" : [[1,2,3,...]...], "last": 12345 }
```

The problem is the "key" is also part of data, it is not a field named "key", so I cannot use a class/struct, I had to use a `IDictionary<string, int[][]>` for the first part, but then the "last" part will throw an exception, because it is a single integer rather than an array of arrays.
This is what I've tried:

```
var dec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, int[][]>>(data);
```

This throws json exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 1501555920 to type 'System.Decimal[][]'. Path 'last'.

```
//define a class
public class DPInfo
{
    public decimal[][] points { get; set; }
    public long last { get; set; }
}
var dec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DPInfo>(data);
```

This will not work because the field name of the array is dynamic, so `points` will contains nothing after this.

Any way I can fix this?

Comment: Is there just one `keyXXX` in the JSON or multiple of them with different `XXX` values?

Comment: There is just one but it's name varies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom `JsonConverter` to solve this.  Here is one that should work:

```
public class DPInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DPInfo);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        JProperty points = obj.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name != "last");

        DPInfo info = new DPInfo
        {
            key = points.Name,   // remove this line if you don't need the key
            points = points.Value.ToObject<decimal[][]>(),
            last = (long)obj["last"]
        };

        return info;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, just add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DPInfoConverter))]
public class DPInfo
{
    public string key { get; set; }   // remove this line if you don't need the key
    public decimal[][] points { get; set; }
    public long last { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize as usual, and it should work:

```
string json = @"
{
  ""keyXXX"": [[1, 2, 3]],
  ""last"": 12345
}";

DPInfo info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DPInfo>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7S6STp

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JObject.Parse` to parse your string into a `dynamic` variable. It would at least ensure that the conversion from string to JSON succeeds, but then it would be up to you to validate that there is a value in each property before accessing it.

In your case the statement would look like this:

```
dynamic data = JObject.Parse("{ 'keyXXX' : [[1,2,3,...]...], 'last': 12345 }");
```